# Объявление ссылки на объект объекта класса

Tags: c#, json

Есть классы-шаблоны под JSON.

Я для своего удобства хочу создать ссылку на объект объекта класса.

Короче говоря, грубый пример:

```
public class A {
    B b = new B();
    public int ref i = b.i; << tyt

    public class B {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

Как сделать подобную ссылку?

Comment: реализовать свойство например, у которого `get` будет брать значение из объекта, а `set` - устанавливать

Comment: @Grundy отлично, подходит. Оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одним из вариантом может стать создание свойства у которого `get` будет брать значение из объекта, а `set` - устанавливать:

```
public class A {
    B b = new B();
    public int i { get => b.i; set => b.i=value; }

    public class B {
        public int i = 0;
    }
}
```